# LINQ: Specified cast is not valid occurs intermittedly

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have an application that has started throwing "Specified cast is not valid" exceptions occassionally. I cannot recreate this error consistently and it is driving me and my users crazy.

Offending code:

```
public Complaint GetComplaintById(int Id)
{
    Complaint complaint = (from c in _context.cts_complaints
                           join ud in _context.cts_user_details on c.CreatedBy equals ud.UserId
                           where c.Id == Id
                           select new Complaint
                           {
                              Id = c.Id,
                              CompanyId = c.CompanyId,
                              ComplaintTypeId = c.ComplaintTypeId,
                              CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                              ReportCategoryId = c.ReportCategoryId,
                              ParentId = c.ParentId,
                              LanguageId = c.LanguageId,
                              AreaId = c.AreaId,
                              Title = c.Title,
                              Description = c.Description,
                              ResponseDue = c.ResponseDue,
                              DateReceived = c.DateReceived,
                              FPSCNumber = c.FPSCNumber,
                              FPSCRepresentative = c.FPSCRepresentative,
                              ContactMethodId = c.ContactMethodId,
                              ContactedBy = c.ContactedBy,
                              CreatedDate = c.CreatedDate,
                              CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy,
                              CreatedByName = ud.Name,
                              Status = c.Status,
                              AttachmentsArchived = c.AttachmentsArchived,
                              Timestamp = c.Timestamp,
                            }).FirstOrDefault();

    complaint.Users = this.GetUsersByComplaintId(Id);

    return complaint;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ComplaintTracking.Business.Data.SqlComplaintRepository.GetComplaintById(Int32 Id) in C:\SourceCode2010\ComplaintTracking\Service Pack\1.0 ComplaintTracking\ComplaintTracking.Business\Data\SqlComplaintRepository.cs:line 20
   at ComplaintTracking.Business.Managers.ComplaintManager.GetComplaintById(Int32 Id) in C:\SourceCode2010\ComplaintTracking\Service Pack\1.0 ComplaintTracking\ComplaintTracking.Business\Managers\ComplaintManager.cs:line 33
   at ComplaintTracking.Web.UserControls.ComplaintViews.ResolveViewPresenter.Init() in C:\SourceCode2010\ComplaintTracking\Service Pack\1.0 ComplaintTracking\ComplaintTracking.Web\UserControls\ComplaintViews\ResolveViewPresenter.cs:line 39
   at ComplaintTracking.Web.Library.BaseUserControl`2.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in C:\SourceCode2010\ComplaintTracking\Service Pack\1.0 ComplaintTracking\ComplaintTracking.Web\Library\BaseUserControl.cs:line 56
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

**Update:**
I am attempting to make use of the Repository pattern. I have a LINQ 2 SQL ORM object called cts_complaints which is a 1-1 mapping from my SQL Server table dbo.cts_complaints. Within my application, I have a model called Complaint. My repository is mapping from cts_complaints to Complaint.

```
[HasSelfValidation]
public class Complaint
{
    public Complaint()
    {
    CreatedBy = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    DateReceived = DateTime.Now;
    Users = new List<ComplaintUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ComplaintTypeId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ReportCategoryId { get; internal set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int? AreaId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResponseDue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
    public string FPSCNumber { get; set; }
    public string FPSCRepresentative { get; set; }
    public int ContactMethodId { get; set; }
    public string ContactedBy { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool AttachmentsArchived { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; internal set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; internal set; }
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }       
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; internal set; }
    public List<ComplaintUser> Users { get; internal set; }

    [SelfValidation()]
    public void ValidateUsers(ValidationResults results)
    {
    //if id is 0 it's new.  There must be user
    if (Users.Count==0)
            results.AddResult(new ValidationResult("You must assign at least one user.", this, "Users", "", null));

    }
}
```

cts_complaints:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cts_complaint](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ComplaintTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReportCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [LanguageId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AreaId] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ResponseDue] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateReceived] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [FPSCNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FPSCRepresentative] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ContactMethodId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AttachmentsArchived] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cts_complaint] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

cts_user_details:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cts_user_detail](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ManagerEmail] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Role] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cts_user_detail_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to the query vs. the projection?

Comment: @jonnyGold I'm not quite sure what you mean? My user could open a record with no issue, leave and come back, and the error above will appear.

Comment: I mean have you determined whether it is `from c in _context.cts_complaints...where c.Id == Id` or `select new Complaint{...}` that is throwing the exception?

Comment: @jonnyGold That is a good point. I'm not sure how I could check that when I can't easily recreate it. The stack trace shows it is happening in FirstOrDefault.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is tripping the enumerator, so its going to look guilty. Is a `Complaint` the same shape as a `cts_complaints`?  Why project into `Complaint` class at all?

Comment: @jonnyGold I have updated the question to include more detail about the tables and classes involved here.

Comment: Are you logging the IDs used when that exception happens? It must be data-specific.

Comment: @jonnyGold Yes, I know which user and record is being referenced when this exception occurs. The user reported the issue and then we both attempt to access the record again, there is no issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and the problem also occurred intermittently.

The cause was a type mismatch between the column type in the database and the field type in the .dbml file

So perhaps check that the types in the auto-generated linq2sql classes (i.e. cts_complaints, not the model class Complaint which I assume you coded yourself) match the types in the database.

(Details for my specific case: In the linq2sql .dbml file there was a field with type double but in the database the column was datetime - not sure how that happened - maybe originally the DB column and .dbml field had the same type and then someone change the type in the DB without re-generating the .dbml file).

Comment: +1 I had your version of this problem, but thanks to you, it's now fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Error :** Cast is invalid  (While trying to load data into datagrid from entity using LINQ)

**Cause :** Data type is different in mapping entities and SQL server table.

**Example :** In my case I was using an int in the Entity class and a bigint in the DB, that's why I was getting the error.