# Linq: Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

```
int Clinicid = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["ClinicID"].ToString());
        string editPid = Request["editid"].ToString();

        dynamic edt = (from ed in dc.dentist_addnewpatientmodifies
                       where ed.PatientID == editPid && ed.ClinicID == Clinicid
                       select ed).FirstOrDefault();
```

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you casting int to int?

Comment: before it was in string I forget to remove it. but it was not the problem.

Comment: There is no casting available here. Have you tried after removing the cast?

Comment: I tried all the possible ways

Comment: Seems given code is not enough. Need more inputs like the model, sql table schema.

Comment: var edt = (from ed in dc.dentist_addnewpatientmodifies select ed).FirstOrDefault();  Even this is also not working

Comment: I suspect either: ed.PatientID isn't a string (varchar) or  ed.ClinicID isn't an int.

Comment: In my entity ClinicId is of int datatype and patientid is of string datatype.

Comment: Possible post your model here.

Comment: can you provide error message and stack trace?

Comment: Above is the Error message and stack trace

Comment: try see this post:[LINQ: Specified cast is not valid occurs intermittedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197278/linq-specified-cast-is-not-valid-occurs-intermittedly)

Comment: @Nani what is `dentist_addnewpatientmodifies` in your database (table/view/something else)?

Comment: It is table in my database

Comment: It sounds like you changed one of the columns in the database from string to int...  Did you remember to update your edmx/dbml model?